# Uploading diagrams using iPhone 4s

Tags: feature-request

I am currently using stack exchange using my iPhone 4s. How can I upload a diagram to this site from the camera roll?

Comment: This should be asked on [meta.se], not here.

Comment: And it seems it was [added as a feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153551/add-an-image-upload-button-to-the-mobile-site), but not yet implemented (despite being 2+ years old).